# NLog for ASP.NET website doesn't log

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I created simple ASP.NET web-site, added NLog, but it doesn't create any log file, neither throws any exceptions. I tried troubleshoot, but it doesn't help https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

my web.config

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>
<nlog 
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    autoReload="true" 
    throwExceptions="true" 
    internalLogLevel="Off" 
    internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
    <targets>
        <target name="file" type="File" fileName="C:\log.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="File" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="FileNotFound" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file-404" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then I run page below, and nothing happens...

```
public partial class Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("foo");

        Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        log.Error("some test");
        logger.Error("some test 2");
    }
}
```

What is my fault? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attriute of the `<logger>` is a filter (on name)

So you filter now on the loggers with the name "File" and "FileNotFound"

This will write all to the file

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
```

Another option is to use named loggers in C#, so instead of

```
Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

use

```
Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger("FileNotFound");
```

Then you could use `<logger name="FileNotFound" ..>` in your config

Answer (score 0):

Likely that your output directory can't be written to by the IIS user. Try using an output directory relative to the website, like "logs".

Comment: i tried <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/logs/WebSiteLog-${shortdate}.log" but it also doen't work